# nvm specific installation not working on Mac M1 (Ventura)

Tags: node.js, macos, meteor, apple-m1, nvm

I am running a meteor project requiring the node.js version `14.17.3` but running the command `nvm install 14.17.3`  throws an error. It's strange because I used the same command to download version 14.13 with no issues.

error:

```
Downloading and installing node v14.17.3...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.3/node-v14.17.3-darwin-arm64.tar.xz...
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.3/node-v14.17.3-darwin-arm64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /Users/confidential/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.17.3-darwin-arm64/node-v14.17.3-darwin-arm64.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Clang v3.5+ detected! CC or CXX not specified, will use Clang as C/C++ compiler!
Local cache found: ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v14.17.3/node-v14.17.3.tar.xz
Checksums match! Using existing downloaded archive ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v14.17.3/node-v14.17.3.tar.xz
$>./configure --prefix=/Users/confidential/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3 <
Node.js configure: Found Python 3.10.7...
Please use python3.9 or python3.8 or python3.7 or python3.6 or python3.5 or python2.7.
nvm: install v14.17.3 failed!
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `meteor update`?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is a matter of nvm requiring a specific python version when compiling node to install it on your system, something similar happened to me.

If this is not a problem for your system try installing one of the python versions shown in the installation debug message *(python3.9 or python3.8 or python3.7 or python3.6 or python3.5 or python2 .7)*.

You can use pyenv to install a suggested version of python and optionally make that version the global default, then try again to install the node version you need.

- Install pyenv

```
brew install pyenv
```

- Check the python versions installed on your system

```
pyenv versions
```

- List the available python versions to install

```
pyenv install —list
```

- Install a suggested version for example:

```
pyenv install 3.9.0
```

- Optionally make it global

```
pyenv global 3.9.0
```

- Install node

```
nvm install 14.17.3
```

Note that when you try to install node with nvm again it will probably start installing it from source and the process of compiling and installing takes a long time but supposedly that is normal according to this nvm [issue](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1912).

I hope it is useful.